# Maven Spring boot runtime error (jar)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to Springframework and I have recently started working with Spring boot. I have used Chris Henkel's tutorials on Sring with Angular js https://github.com/chrishenkel. I am building the same with spring boot. I keep on encountering this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'blogController' defined in file [C:\Users\arnoldnogo\IdeaProjects\FreightsMatch\target\classes\com\freightsmatch\rest\controllers\BlogController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.freightsmatch.service.BlogService]: : Error creating bean with name 'blogServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.freightsmatch.repositories.BlogEntryRepo com.freightsmatch.service.impl.BlogServiceImpl.entryRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.freightsmatch.repositories.BlogEntryRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'blogServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.freightsmatch.repositories.BlogEntryRepo com.freightsmatch.service.impl.BlogServiceImpl.entryRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.freightsmatch.repositories.BlogEntryRepo] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.freightsmatch.FreightsMatchApplication.main(FreightsMatchApplication.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: This is not a compilation error, but a runtime error. Compilation errors only occur when there's an error in the source code and the compiler cannot compile your code. You can obviously compile and run your code - and you're getting an error at runtime.

Comment: The error says you don't have a bean of type `com.freightsmatch.repositories.BlogEntryRepo` - check your Spring configuration and make sure you have a bean configured of this type.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper I have made the necessary changes on the heading. It has worked successfully